# Datastream not pulling change data from RDS Postgresql

Tags: google-bigquery, data-stream, google-datastream

I followed the on screen instruction to connect datastream from AWS RDS Postgresql to Bigquery. 
Enabled logical replication, added

```
CREATE PUBLICATION [MY_PUBLICATION] FOR ALL TABLES;
SELECT PG_CREATE_LOGICAL_REPLICATION_SLOT('[MY_SLOT_NAME]', 'pgoutput');
```

and

```
CREATE USER [MY_USER] WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD '[MY_PASSWORD]';
GRANT RDS_REPLICATION TO [MY_USER];
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA [MY_SCHEMA] TO [MY_USER];
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA [MY_SCHEMA] TO [MY_USER];
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA [MY_SCHEMA]
GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO [MY_USER];
```

Followed the above steps. 
I can able to pull the data by running backfil. But change data like insert/update are not coming up in bigquery. 
I am seeing this error in logs

It doesn't show exactly what error. Does anyone experienced this issue? Need help to solve this.

Trigged checking user permission and even used superadmin user. still the same

Comment: Tried checking user permission and even used superadmin user. still the same